# Como fechar janela aperta pelo Process Start na automação do c#?

Tags: c#, .net, automatização, testes-automatizados

Olá
Eu estou fazendo uma automação e para isso precisei abrir a janela do Power Options no windows. Para isto utilizei o método:

`Process.Start("Rundll32.exe", "shell32.dll,Control_RunDLL powercfg.cpl");`

Agora que terminei de automatizar preciso fechar essa janela. Já tentei várias combinações de `KillProcess();` mas nenhuma funcionou.

Alguém pode dar uma dica por favor?

Comment: Eu verifiquei que o Process aberto era encerrado e que a janela no Power Options ficava com uma id diferente sob o nome de "explorer.exe" no task manager.

A "solução" encontrada foi listar todos os processos de explorer e fazer um foreach matando todos.

Caso alguém tenha uma solução mais elegante eu aceito de coração.

Answer (score -2):

A função estática Process.Start retorna uma instancia do objeto Process.
que tem uma função .Kill() que faz exatamente o que você precisa.

```
  var process = Process.Start("Rundll32.exe", "shell32.dll,Control_RunDLL powercfg.cpl");

  process.Kill();
```

Você chegou a tentar isso?

Comment: Acabei de testar [`Process.CloseMainWindow()`][https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.closemainwindow?view=net-6.0] e [`Process.Kill()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.kill?view=net-6.0) e  com os applets do painel de controle não funcionam.

Comment: As informações do módulo do processo são `The process's main moduleName is:  rundll32.exe
The process's main module's base address is: 140699511619584
The process's main module's Entry point address is: 140699511646352
The process's main module's File name is: C:\Windows\system32\rundll32.exe`